# Isomorphism of matrix ring with elements from opposite ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

I want to show the map $\phi:M_\mathrm{n} (R) \rightarrow M_\mathrm{n} (R^{op})^{op}$   given by M$\rightarrow $$^t$M is an isomorphism of rings.

I have shown that it is injective and surjective but I am not sure how to show this is well defined and homomorphism .

If we take (R,+,.) and (R$^{op}$,+,*)  then

$\phi$(M.N)=$^t$N * $^t$M but $\phi$(M) * $\phi$(N)= $^t$M * $^t$N

Comment: Note that you also take the opposite matrix ring! So $*$ is not the product on $M_n(R^{op})^{op}$. To show it is an isomorphism, just use the same map as an inverse.

Comment: thanks @red_trumpet